# Problemas com acentuação em carácteres do PostgreSQL e PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Olá! Estou com problemas ao salvar os dados de um formulário em PHP no PostgreSQL.

Atualmente o banco de dados está com LATIN1 e as páginas estão com o Charset em UTF8. Porém já testei com o PostgreSQL em UTF8 e ocorre a mesma situação.

Após a submissão do formulário e impressão do script SQL os dados a serem salvos estão conforme o esperado, porém no banco de dados os dados são salvos como o exemplo abaixo.

Valor a ser salvo: Acentuação.

Valor salvo no banco de dados: AcentuaÃ§Ã£o.

Agradeço a ajuda :D

Comment: Você tentou usar no PostgreSQL: SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'LATIN1';? Provavelmente o PostgreSQL esta considerando que o client encoding não é o LATIN1 (verifique utilizando SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de salvar as informações do formulário, utilize UTF8_DECODE. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```
<?php
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$StrSQL = "INSERT INTO minha_tabela (nome) VALUES ('" . utf8_decode($nome) . "')";
//Programação para gravar no banco de dados....
?>
```

Para exibir uma informação gravada no banco, utilize utf8_encode()